# Android FIle Manipulation (APPEND)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How can I append an string into a text file? I know how to write in a text file but now I want to append using my code but it doesn't append it just writing a new string instead. Here is my code:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = null;
OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
try {
    fOut = openFileOutput("sample.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    osw.append("this is append text");
    osw.close();
    fOut.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(Ticketing.this, "Error: " + e,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        return;
    }
```

Please help! 
Sorry for my bad English. 
Thanks!

Comment: I think there is many codes show how to append file in Java, please search before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mmm... try this..

```
FileOutputStream fOut = null;
OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
try {
    fOut = openFileOutput("sample.txt",MODE_APPEND|MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    osw.write("this is append text");
    osw.write(separator);
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(Ticketing.this,"Error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use `BufferedWriter` to avoid creation of new Strings.

Do something like this:

```
try{        
File file =new File("sample.txt");
FileWriter fW= new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
BufferedWriter bW= new BufferedWriter(fW);
bW.write("this is append text");
bW.close();
    }
catch(Exception e)
   {Log.e("Exception: ", e + " ");}
```

Comment: i am tryng the code above but it gives me an error : 
`error:java.io.FileNotFoundException:/sample.text:Open Failed: EROFS:(Read-only-file system)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this: [FileWriter(File file, boolean append)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

You have to open your File withe `new FileOutputStream("sample.txt", true)`

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)):

> public FileOutputStream(File file,boolean append) throws FileNotFoundException
>
> Creates a file output stream to write to the file represented by the
>   specified File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will
>   be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning. A new
>   FileDescriptor object is created to represent this file connection. 
>   First, if there is a security manager, its checkWrite method is called
>   with the path represented by the file argument as its argument.
>
> If the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason then a FileNotFoundException is thrown.
>
> Parameters:file - the file to be opened for writing´.
>
> append - if true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning